# Outlook 2010 search multiple mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, search, exchange-2010

In our domain, the domain administrator creates a new shared mailbox on exchange 2010, and adds multiple users to that mailbox by using the 'Mannage Full Access Permission...' option of Exchange 2010.

So the shared mailboxes are automatically added to the persons outlook.
[image]

So in my account settings there is no extra mailbox:
[image]

Now searching in the shared mailbox (in my example the LicenseManager mailbox) is impossible.

Looking at the locations to search in outlook 2010:
[image]

Also looking at the indexing option, there is no way to locate the shared mailbox.
How can i get this to work? I'm having full access to a mailbox, but know way to search in that mailbox.

This is so very frustrating

Comment: Is [this](http://superuser.com/questions/261003/outlook-2010-can-you-search-a-shared-mailbox-and-include-subfolders) the same problem? I'm not familiar with shared mailboxes.